# Rationale Behind PCL `shared_ptr` Interfaces

Tags: c++, api-design, point-cloud-library

Many PCL interfaces accept only `shared_ptr<T>` arguments (e.g. `boost::shared_ptr< PointCloud>`). [**Aside**: that is it `boost::shared_ptr` and not `std::shared_ptr` is another issue, but should be fixed in upcoming versions.]

Typically such interfaces are a valid option for multi-threaded applications where object lifetimes need to be managed and prevent shared references objects from going out of scope. However, PCL isn't necessarily used in such a context and this API forces one to create many objects on the heap just to support this API style (and always checking for `nullptr`).

Is there another rationale that I am missing for why this is so?
For local objects, I now need to create a `shared_ptr` with a custom *nop* deleter object just to pass it to the algorithms.

Comment: Exposing non-trivial objects across module boundaries is never not a problem, they have to agree about the memory allocator they use.  shared_ptr can ensure that the module that allocated the object is also the one that destroys it.

Comment: @HansPassant: Does `shared_ptr<>` really transparently pass through module boundaries and allow calling the "remote" dealloc? Even if so, I wonder if this is the real consideration for PCL as many uses do not need this and the nop-deleter option is clunky.

Comment: You mean why they use `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr` or why they don't accept a interface for both, or why they don't accept raw pointer that you initialized with `new`?

Comment: I mean why only a `shared_ptr<>` interface and e.g. no reference or raw (non-owning) pointer version.

Comment: @AdiShavit I don't know about which particular part of the pcl you are talking, but those parts that expect a `shared_ptr`  as input normally indeed need to own it until the data is processed. If you e.g. take the `VoxelGrid`  and the `setInputCloud`  and `filter` function, the gird has to own the input cloud until filter is called, as of that `shared_ptr`  is used for `setInputCloud`  and reference is used for `filter`, only that way pcl can guarantee that the input cloud is not deleted before `filter`  is called.

Comment: @AdiShavit This could be circumvented with a different kind of API that uses streaming/pipes/chaining - like d3.js does. But that you would result in problems if you want to reuse intermediate results, that might be expensive to calculate.

Comment: @t.niese This seems like an overly protective API, instead of, say, taking a `const &`. I can only understand this (costly) decision for uses such as cross module boundaries or multithreading. AFAIK, these are not necessarily the only ways PCL is used. Hence my puzzlement. All these `shared_ptr` have a cost of self overhead and basically changing the way objects are stored and manipulated in the program. Not a very C++-ish way of writing code (where unnecessary).

Comment: @AdiShavit `shared_ptr` is not not about multithreading, it is about ownership. So if you have `pcl::VoxelGrid grid; sor.setInputCloud (input); ... ; sor.filter (*output);` and then voxel grid has to own `input` until `filter` is called. `filter` indeed takes the object as `&` as it only requires it till the end of that call, and it could use threads inside without problems. But `input` is a shared ownership, `const &` would not bring any lifetime guarantee. For this particular case a `sor.filter(*cloud, *cloud_filtered);` API might be an idea, for one time filtering.

Comment: @AdiShavit `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, `observer_ptr`,  `optional` and `ref` are introduced to replace `new`, `delete` and  raw pointers. So in modern c++-ish you don't want to deal with `new` and `delete`. Yes `shared_ptr` have an overhead if copied, but besides that they behave the same as `new`. If you are talking about that you can't create our cloud object on stack, most of its relevant data is on heap anyway, and the benefit of reusing precalculated data if you apply a method with different parameters on the same cloud is much higher than the `shared_ptr` _overhead_ of one increment.

Comment: IMHO the reason why the API of PCL uses `boost::shared_ptr`'s is simple. 
Point Clouds can become very large leading to huge memory consumption.
Hence, you should almost always allocate the memory on the heap when dealing with point clouds.

When PCL was first implemented, C++11 was not really out yet (or people didn't use it yet), so you could not use STL's `std::shared_ptr`.

I think in order to have an easy to use API, they implemented the function calls with `shared_ptr`'s, since the point cloud objects will be `shared_ptr`'s anyways.